# Unir dos tablas con todos los resultados de ambas

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con dos tablas y una consulta que me esta volviendo loco.

Tengo la tabla meses con los meses del año y una tabla de datos que tienen una fecha de creacion.

La cuestión es que deseo obtener la suma de registros de la segunda tabla por mes.

Digamos en enero tengo dos registros entonces me devolvería id 1 numrecords 2 pero si en febrero no tengo datos debería devolver id 2 numrecords 0.

Indudablemente hay algo que no estoy entendiendo de los join porque probé todos los join .

[image: Imagen resultado esperado consulta que tengo:]

```
select Month(table1.date_recived) as Month,  count(*) as numRecords 
from table1
 JOIN months on Month(date_recived)=months.id
 
where 
CAST(date_recived AS DATE)  between CAST(DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AS DATE) and CAST(curdate() AS DATE)  
OR CAST(date_recived AS DATE)  in( select months.id) 
Group By Month
```

order by Month

resultado obtenido
[[image: Resultado actual]]

La primer tabla (Table1) proviene de un select

```
select Month(date_recived) as Month,  count(*) as numRecords 
    from alarms_histories 
    
     
    where 
    CAST(date_recived AS DATE)  between CAST(DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AS DATE) and CAST(curdate() AS DATE)  
   Group By Month
```

A ese select es el que realmente quiero que me ponga en los meses que no estan 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo una query alternativa a la que te sugieren los compañeros de arriba:

```
select m.id, m.name, count(t.date_recived) countrows 
from #months m 
left join #table1 t on m.id = month(t.date_recived)
group by m.id, m.name order by m.id
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrKnZ.png]

**IMPORTANTE**: Si la necesitas para un proyecto en producción, te recomiendo crear en Tabla1 una columna con el número de mes + un índice para usarlo en el cruce del inner join (así evitas la función calculada "m.id = month(t.date_recived)" que estoy dejando en el ejemplo), eso es por temas de rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

1. Crear una sub consulta que cuente los registros por mes y luego aplicar un `right join` externo con la tabla months.

---

```
SELECT month,
       numrecords
FROM   (SELECT Month(table1.date_recived) AS Month,
               Count(table1.date_recived) AS numRecords
        FROM   table1
        WHERE  Cast(date_recived AS date) BETWEEN
               Cast(Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 12
               month)
                       AS date) AND
               Cast(Curdate() AS date)
                OR Cast(date_recived AS date) IN(SELECT months.id)
        GROUP  BY month)tabla1
       RIGHT JOIN months
               ON month = months.id
```

Comment: Indudablemente me explique mal. La tabla1 viene del select global que se esta ejecutando por lo tanto countrows   no existe y no es un campo real. Tabla uno viene de la consulta que estoy ejecutando.

Comment: La edite xq creo no se entendio

Comment: De acuerdo. Ya edité la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día amigo, te recomiendo hacer un left join a tu tabla, la cual compara todos los datos de la tabla A (en este caso la tabla_months) y checa los match de la tabla B(tabla1) y donde no encuentra coincidencia le coloca un 0.

```
Select tabla_months.id, tabla_months.nombre,ifnull(tabla1.countrows,0) as countrows from tabla_months left join tabla1 on tabla1.id=tabla_months.id order by tabla_months.id asc;
```

Se le coloca la función **IFNULL** para que en lugar de NULL te devuelva un valor normalizado, en este caso 0.
El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y te funcione amigo.